# convert this ADODB crystal report to OLEDB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports, oledb, adodb

I don't know how to convert the ADODB into a OLEDB.
I'm having problem in DataTable, Recordset and Recordcount. 
I really don't know how to convert this into OLEDB

ADODB Module

```
Public con As New ADODB.Connection
Public rec As New ADODB.Recordset
Public flag As New Integer
Public temp As New Integer

Public Sub connect()
    Dim path As String
    path = Application.StartupPath & "\dbPSITSms.mdb"
    con.Open("provider=microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source = " & path)
End Sub
```

ADODB CrystalReportViewer1 Form

```
Private Sub CrystalReport_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("psitscode")
    dt.Columns.Add("studnum")
    dt.Columns.Add("sy")
    dt.Columns.Add("total")
    connect()
    rec.Open("SELECT * FROM tableTransaction", con, 3, 3)
    If rec.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        Do Until rec.EOF
            dt.Rows.Add(rec("psitscode").Value, rec("studnum").Value, rec("sy").Value, rec("total").Value)
            rec.MoveNext()
        Loop
    End If
    rec.Close()
    con.Close()

    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New CrystalReport1
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt)
    Me.CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = rptDoc
    Me.CrystalReportViewer.Refresh()
End Sub
```

here is my OLEDB

```
Public Class DataTransaction
Dim connString As New ConnectionString
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

Public Function List(ByVal sql As String) As DataSet
    con.ConnectionString = connString.connectionString
    con.Open()
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "data")
    con.Close()
    List = ds
End Function

Public Sub ExecuteSql(ByVal sql As String)
    con.ConnectionString = connString.connectionString
    con.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = sql
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
Public Function connectionString() As String
    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dbPharmacy.accdb"
End Function
```

Please help me experts. thanks

Comment: You said, you have a problem, but you didn't say what IS your problem. As of now, your question falls under off-topic as "why this code is not working". To me - looks fine. I don't see any issues. You need to explain where and what issue you have

Comment: sorry sir, the problem i'm referring to is about ADODB.recordset.

Comment: My friend, imagine that you did not write this question. Go ahead - read it and tell me if you see, where is the question here? "I have a problem" is not a question. There is no question here. May be this is the reason nobody  answers it...

Comment: ahm, what about. How to convert ADODB to OLEDB?

Comment: Too broad and opinion based - this is all I can say

Answer (score 0):

This would be a line by line conversion of your ADODB code (I ignored the OLEDB stuff you had, I used your code to create the DataTable and setup the report but plugged in the OleDb syntax to populate it under the same pattern you used with ADODB).

The "Using" statements ensure that things are cleaned up and disposed of after they're used.

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("psitscode")
    dt.Columns.Add("studnum")
    dt.Columns.Add("sy")
    dt.Columns.Add("total")

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Your OleDb Connection String")
        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = conn.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tableTransaction"

            Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While dr.Read
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr("psitscode"), dr("studnum"), dr("sy"), dr("total").Value)
                End While

                dr.Close()
            End Using

        End Using

        conn.Close()
    End Using

    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New CrystalReport1
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt)
    Me.CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = rptDoc
    Me.CrystalReportViewer.Refresh()
```

Comment: thanks sir. i really appreciate your help. thanks a lot